# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0, without any typo in connectionString

Tags: c#, mysql, code-first

I carefully read all the answers given to similar questions about this argument, but I did not find a solution fit for my problem.

### In brief: I have a C# solution using MySQL and Prism; my app.config has the following EntityFramework section:

```
<entityFramework>
   <defaultConnectionFactory ype="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
      <connectionStrings configSource="Connections.config" />
```

---

### The file Connections.config contains the following code:

```
  <add name="DataContext"
       connectionString = "Server=localhost; Port=3306; Database=dbName; uid=<correct user>; pwd=<correct password>" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

---

### I am sure that I have no typo in the configuration code, specially in the connection string; indeed, code-migration works like a charm; but, when I come to the very first access to the DataContext, I receive the infamous exception message. The code is the following:

```
using MyApp.DataAccess;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace myApp.Core
{
    public class UserManager : IUserManager
   {
      private UserAccessLevels _level;
      (...)
      private DataContext DataContext { get; }

      public UserManager(DataContext dc) { // dc is injected by DI container
         DataContext = dc ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(DataContext));

         var winUserId = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
         var loginName = winUserId.Name.Substring(winUserId.Name.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
         // In the following line I have the error:
         var usr = DataContext.AppUser.SingleOrDefault(x => x.LoginId == loginName);
```

---

I would really appreciate any hint, or a real illumination... thanks to you all

Update:

### as requested, here follow the code of my DataContext class:

```
   [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
   public partial class DataContext : DbContext
   {

      (... IDbSets registration ...)

      public DataContext() : base("DataContext") {
         this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
      }

      (... the rest of code ...)
```

---

Again, remember that the code migrations are working perfectly; it's a very strange behavior.

Comment: can you please share the `DataContext` class code?, the constructor part specially

Answer (score 0):

in your connections.config file create a section with `connectionStrings` as the name of the node in main `Web.config` file here is the code that might solve your issue.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DataContext"
       connectionString = "Server=localhost; Port=3306; Database=dbName; uid=<correct user>; pwd=<correct password>" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Alas, it does not, because I had only forgotten to copy and past the tags with the code... but they are present :)

Comment: I guess you must have tried this, sorry for asking...putting the same connection string back to main app.config works?